# How to use state as checked atribute in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a switch checkbox in render, so one important attribute to detect if it's `checked` or not is `defaultChecked`. I set the state previously in the `componentWillReceiveProps`. I try first putting the state as attribute but I'm getting an error `Unexpected token` when it compiles the code with `babel.js`. After I try using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it's still not working (bottom error).

First try:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" {this.state.required} />
```

App.jsx

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            required: ''
        };
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ){
        //more code    
        this.setState({
            required: 'defaultChecked'
        });
    };

    render() {
      return(
        <div id="section">                
            <div className="bottom-question">
                <div>
                    <div className="onoffswitch-add pull-left">
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               name="onoffswitch" 
                               dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.state.required} />

                        <label className="onoffswitch-label-add" htmlFor="switch-required">
                            <div className="onoffswitch-inner-add"></div>
                            <div className="onoffswitch-switch-add"></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Error:

```
The full text of the error you just encountered is:

input is a void element tag and must neither have `children` 
nor use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Check the render method of EditInput
```

Comment: Check this once about how to use checkbox in reactjs https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to use the `checked` property to apply a check to the checkbox input in javascript

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" checked={this.state.required === 'defaultChecked'} />
```

when you set the state of required to be whatever you want it to be (in this case you are using the string `'defaultChecked'`) you need to tell the input to check itself or not based on that.

I would recommend you refactor the state variable to be a boolean and call it `checked` like so

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checked: false
        };
    };

    componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ){
        //more code    
        this.setState({
            checked: true
        });
    };

    render() {
      return(
        <div id="section">                
            <div className="bottom-question">
                <div>
                    <div className="onoffswitch-add pull-left">
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                               name="onoffswitch" 
                               checked={this.state.checked} />

                        <label className="onoffswitch-label-add" htmlFor="switch-required">
                            <div className="onoffswitch-inner-add"></div>
                            <div className="onoffswitch-switch-add"></div>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ted sorry for that. One word makes the difference. Thanks John.

Comment: @Ted thanks :) gotta read between the lines sometimes! No worries though Angel... It happens to everyone :) thanks for the quick accept!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `<input required={this.state.required} />`

Comment: Please take as reference my comment in @XPLOT1ON answer.

Comment: In that case you can do the same thing with `disabled` instead of `required`

Answer (score 1):

React has an attribute for this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" disabled={this.state.required} />
```

where `this.state.required` is a `boolean`

Comment: I think there are a confusion with attribute `required` because that word was in the code. But what I need it's shows the `switch button` active or inactive depending on that state.

Comment: This isn't a special attribute of react, it's just a standard html attribute

Comment: @AngelCuenca I have just updated my answer to disabled instead of required.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to have a `disabled` prop for your button that is `true` when the checkbox is not checked, and `false` when it is.

To do this, start with a state variable that stores the checkbox's value. Then add a function that is fired on the `onChange` event which toggles the state from true-> false and vice versa.

The button should then be disabled when the checkbox is unchecked.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checkboxState: false
    };
  }
  
  toggleCheckbox = () => {
    this.setState({checkboxState: !this.state.checkboxState});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" onChange={this.toggleCheckbox} />
        <input type="submit" disabled={!this.state.checkboxState} value="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Please take as reference my comment in @XPLOT1ON answer.

Comment: @AngelCuenca, this wasn't any helpful?

Comment: @Cris I do not think so. I only need to take control over whether it is 'checked' or not the button. Not disabled or not.

Comment: Okay, so just remove the `disabled={...` part :)